Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2 fails with PHC in ndk-build
When updating Android Gradle Plugin from 4.2.2 to 7.4.2 the task 'googleplayGbillingDebug' fails with the following error message:
googleplayGbillingDebug|x86_64 : pch.precompiled.h-googleplayGbillingDebugX86_64-libexternaldeps.abi 'libexternaldeps' is invalid. Valid values are 'armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64'
The content generated in android_gradle_build.json:
"pch.precompiled.h-googleplayGbillingDebugX86_64-libexternaldeps": {
    "buildCommandComponents": [
      "/Users/[redacted]/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/24.0.8215888/ndk-build",
      "NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null",
      .
      .
      .  
  "/Users/[redacted]/mobileintegrated/Projects/BigCasino/android/PopSlots/popSlots/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/[redacted]/obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/externaldeps/libexternaldeps/pch.precompiled.h.gch"
    ],
    "toolchain": "toolchain-libexternaldeps",
    "abi": "libexternaldeps",
    "artifactName": "pch.precompiled.h",
    "output": "/Users/[redacted]/mobileintegrated/Projects/BigCasino/android/PopSlots/popSlots/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/[redacted]/obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/externaldeps/libexternaldeps/pch.precompiled.h.gch"
}

My gradle.build file, along with all Android.mk and Application.mk files, are correctly configured and function properly with older versions of the plugin.
I attempted to identify any deprecation issues in my build.gradle related to the new Gradle plugin, but I found no problems.
